# Reader class game board: returning boolean values properly

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, boolean-expression

This is my first post but I've stalked stack overflow a while. I have an assignment to make a `Board` class that represents a tic tac toe board. I also have to make a `Reader` class that reads in tic tac toe moves from a file and plays them to the board (instead of...you know..players...actually playing the game themselves).

The game board is set up as 2d array likeso

```
array[row][column]
00 01 02
10 11 12
20 21 22
```

The requirements for the assignment want a bool function in the `Reader` class to read the values into the `Board` object from .txt file and play the game. However, if the file tries to play the same move twice, it should return `false`.(nota bene: first move is always x) For example:

```
game.txt
01 
11
12
01
```

should return `false` because o can't play in 01 since x started off there.

It should also return `false` if the game has finished but there are more "plays" in the file. For example:

```
game2.txt
00
10
11
12
22
02
```

o tries to play `02` even though `x` has already won. This should also return `false` (same if o wins somehow).

Now, I can't get anything to return properly. The code is at this link (I know, I know...not the best sharing method but I'm a beginner and I couldn't figure out how to get stack to accept it):

```
bool Reader::readGameFile(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    int row, column;
    bool flagVar = true;
    inputFile.open(fileName);

    if (inputFile)
    {    
        while(inputFile >> row >> column) //keep looping until the file    runs out of input
        {    
            if (board.checkOneBlank(row, column))
            {
                if(board.gameState() == X_WON)
                    flagVar = false;
                if(board.gameState() == O_WON)
                    flagVar = false;
                if(board.gameState() == UNFINISHED)
                    flagVar = true;
                board.makeMove(row, column, playerTurn);
                if(playerTurn == 'x')
                {
                    playerTurn = 'o';
                }
                else
                {
                    playerTurn = 'x';
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if(flagVar)
        return true;
    else if(flagVar == false)
        return false;
    else if (board.gameState() == DRAW)
        return true;
    else
        return true;
    inputFile.close();
}
```

The `Board` class has the functions:

```
bool makeMove(int, int char); // which calls checkOneBlank and will record a move to the board if it is blank
void print();                 // which prints the board  
bool checkOneBlank(int, int); // checks to see if a value is blank
bool checkState(char);        // checks to see if there are any horizontal, vertical, or diagonal wins
bool checkAllBlanks();        // checks to see if there are any blanks left on the board and counts them. if there are more than 0 then it returns false (used to check for a draw)
Game game();                  // checks to see if the game has an x winner, an o winner, a draw, or is unfinished. is an enumerated data type due to the specifications of the project
```

All of these functions have been tested thoroghly. They work as expected.

I would really appreciate any help getting the function I posted above working properly. This has been driving me crazy. Thanks!

Edit: I am wondering how to make sure that bool values return properly. My question is how to make these loops function. I must have the while loop run to the end of the file, even if the player is still playing. That is in the project specifications.

Comment: you should make move on board and change player only if game is unfinished (now you do it anyway). also you should close file before! returning from function. Also you could just return flagVar (result of executing will be same as your current code)

Comment: @AndrewKashpur `~ifstream` closes the file. `ifstream inputFile(filename)` is all that is neccecary

Answer (score 0):

I must say it is hard to understand what your actual question is , but here is my hypothesis.
Your players keep taking moves even though the other has won... and you are wondering why they are doing that.

They are doing that because you are never breaking out of the while loop. I would suggest that the `makeMove` method just return your game state. As soon as you execute that method , check your return values and if x or y have won or if it is a draw, use the `break` command to exit the while loop.

That would remove any need for the `gameState` method, however you can keep it if you really need to and instead of having `makeMove` return the state, you can just have it modify the state and check it using `gameState` .

There are many other opportunities to simplify and make this code better but I will leave you to find them.

Comment: I would do something like that if I had free reign of the project. I do not...it was designed by my professor and I will get points taken away if I did something like the makeMove method return the game state.

Comment: Strange design choice, but in the end the point is not what method is returning which values.
As I said, you can take the second approach and retain the interface of your board class , just check the state post making a move and break when you are in a victory or draw state.

Comment: Additionally, you're right -- I didn't actually as a question. My question is this: how do I make the code return the bool values properly? The project specifications require that I keep the while loop running until the very end of the .txt file.

Comment: I don't see any place where `bools` would be returned incorrectly, also, if the specs require you to run the program till the end of the file the specs are stupid and your should say as much to your professor.

If a victory or draw condition is found running the loop over a file is irrelevant.. There are a number of ways of doing this if you really want to ... just set a bool indicating that the game is over and check that bool as the first thing in your loop and presto ... the code will pointlessly loop and read the file

Comment: Ah, well , here is why you may be getting an unexpected result out of `readGameFile` , player `o` wins ... but you keep reading the file and keep making moves , you have not shared the rest of your code so idk what would happen in a situation where one player has won and moves keep getting made.

This situation will probably mess with `flagVar` and set it to true or something. That would be why you get an improper return.

The problem, I will repeat is not with returning the bool, the problem is with your game going on even though a player has won.

Comment: I don't disagree. I've been frustrated with the design of this project from the beginning and am not sure what it is supposed to be teaching me. 

Anyway, essentially, when a player has won and moved keep getting made, the while loop keeps going and keeps making moves . That's why there are if statements to check for wins. Only if there is a win do I want the flag to be set to false, that way I can say that the game had already been won but it kept playing. 

Essentially we're supposed to specifically check for games that have been won(finished) but still have moves left in the file.

Comment: Your checks will do nothing to stop the pollution of state ... if you had 5 moves in your file ... and 3 moves in `o` wins ... what happens when `board.makeMove(row, column, playerTurn);` executes ?

Honestly, the fix that I was hoping that you would see by yourself is simply changing `if (board.checkOneBlank(row, column))` to `if (board.checkOneBlank(row, column) && flagVar)` and setting `flagVar` to true before the while loop starts.

Comment: just to reiterate , your if statements that check for wins will do nothing to stop `board.makeMove(row, column, playerTurn);` from being executed and polluting your game state.

Comment: I'm not sure I can get full credit and do that. That's my problem - makeMove only records an x or an o in a blank. It doesn't do anything with game state and even though I technically could, that wouldn't solve the problem my professor is asking me to look for. Also, flagvar is already set to true before the while loop starts.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Polluting the game state, as you keep saying, is exactly what the Prof wants.

Comment: In that case... there is no way this program can run correctly. If the game is over and you can still make illegal moves ... you will get incorrect results !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to stop looping when you have your desired result is to `return` that result.

```
bool Reader::readGameFile(string fileName)
{
    ifstream inputFile(fileName); 
    // Opens the file. When inputFile is destroyed, the file is closed
    // The principle of doing an action at the end of a scope, by using 
    // some object's destructor is called RAII. It is one of the most important 
    // parts of idiomatic C++

    for (int row, column; inputFile >> row >> column;) 
    {    
        // We only need row and column within the loop, so they are only defined here
        if (board.checkOneBlank(row, column))
        {
            board.makeMove(row, column, playerTurn);
            // move first, so that we check the state after the move
            // otherwise we don't return the correct result if a win 
            // happens as the last move in a file

            if(board.gameState() == X_WON)
                return false;
            if(board.gameState() == O_WON)
                return false;
            if(board.gameState() == DRAW)
                return true;
            // We are done with this function. 
            // Because our local objects tidy up after themselves, 
            // we don't need any "goto cleanup" etc.

            if(playerTurn == 'x')
            {
                playerTurn = 'o';
            }
            else
            {
                playerTurn = 'x';
            }

        }
    }
    // always have to return a value.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `playerTurn` is suspicious here, it should probably be a parameter (char & if it needs to remain modified) or a local value, and not a global.

Comment: N.B. not reading the whole file is indistinguishable from reading the whole file and doing nothing with the remainder.

Comment: If you are pressed, you can include a `bool hasResult = false, result = true;` change the if condition to `if (!hasResult && board.checkOneBlank(row, column))` and set `hasResult and result` instead of returning